# Bash script that reads 1.5 lines

Tags: bash, file-io

I have a text file like

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

I want to write a bash script which reads the file and returns

```
ab
bc
cd
de
ef
```

my attempt so far is a script which reads 2 by 2 lines, and trying to hold the second variable in order to reuse it in the next turn. But my attempt so far is:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read LINE
do let "COUNT++";
        if [[ $COUNT == 2 ]]; then
                echo $PREV $LINE
                COUNT=0
                LINE=$PREV2
        else
                PREV="$LINE"
        fi
done
```

The best I could manage was a list like

```
ab
cd
de
f
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use:

```
p=
q=
while read -r p; do
   [[ -n "$q" ]] && echo "$q$p"
   q="$p"
done < file
ab
bc
cd
de
ef
```

Comment: It does exactly what I intended! However I would be grateful if you explained the logic behind your algorithm, how different it is from my own mistaken one.

Comment: Actually rather than using a counter I use a simple method of storing previous line a variable `q`. As you can see printing only starts from 2nd line onwards when at least one previous line is there. Rest is pretty simple as I combine previous and current lines in `echo` as `echo "$q$p"`.

Comment: You can also initialize `q` using `{ read -r q; while read -r p; do echo "$q$p"; q="$p"; done; } < file`. It saves the non-empty test on `$q`, but is arguably no simpler visually. You can skip the initializations for `p` and `q`, though; the code doesn't depend on the distinction between an unset variable and a null-valued variable.

Comment: Yes agreed. Primary reason why I initialized `q` was during my testing of running same script again `q` was already set as `f` and caused `[[ -n "$q" ]]` condition to fail. Of course `p` doesn't require any initialization.

Answer (score 3):

You do not really need a Bash script to do that

```
$ cat t.txt
a
b
c
d
e
f
$ paste -d '' <(head -n -1 t.txt) <(tail  -n +2 t.txt)
ab
bc
cd
de
ef
```

If you really need a script because of training purposes, see @anubhava's answer. Your line `LINE=$PREV2` is having no effect as `$PREV2` is probably a typo, and the value assigned to `LINE` will be overwritten at the beginning of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You can use perl too

```
perl -nle '$f && print $f.$_; $f=$_'
```

prints

```
ab
bc
cd
de
ef
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with this `awk`:

```
awk 'f{print f $1}{f=$1}' file
```

Comment: +1 I like this `awk`, this uses same algorithm as my BASH script. It can be `awk 'f{print f $1}{f=$1}' file` also.

Comment: Yup, it is the best algorithm for this job I think.  Thanks for pointing out that the quotes aren't necessary :)

Answer (score 0):

how about this awk one-liner:

```
awk '{a[NR]=$0}END{for(i=1;i+1<=NR;i++)print a[i]a[i+1]}' file
```

outputs:

```
ab
bc
cd
de
ef
```